# Collection inside a Backbone model

Tags: backbone.js

I want to create a Backbone model and store a collection of another model into its property. So, there are parent and child model. Each parent has one or more children stored as an array inside its property.

The JSON will be like this.

```
Parent = {
    name: 'Name',
    age: 'Age',
    children:
        [{name: 'Name', age: 'Age'},
        {name: 'Name', age: 'Age'},
        {name: 'Name', age: 'Age'}]
}
```

I've tried to create both model and insert one inside the other but still has no solution. And I don't want to use parse or other server things.

So, is there any solution or better way to achieve that?

Comment: You have to override the `parse()` method of the parent model indeed. Or use libraries like `Backbone.relational`.

Comment: Actually, I don't do server things because this app will only show the output in DOM, not database.

Comment: You do not have to do any server things, you can just override `.fetch()` to consume any source [even a vanilla object], and `.parse()` accordingly. Otherwise, create first the model, then the collection, then `yourModel.set('attributeName', collection)`and you are good to go ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand you want to create a model with this data and if there  are `children` inside model to make a collection of same models inside.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.set('children', new Persons(this.get('children')));
    }
});

var Persons = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});
```

1. On the model creation - `initialize: function () {...}`
2. Lets take our children array - `this.get('children')`
3. And make a collection - `new Persons(...)`
4. Collection will create models itself
5. And put everything back - `this.set('children', ...);`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6y1vsb3m/1/) - run and see result in console.

Comment: It does work but my plan is actually to nest every children model into parent whenever a child model created. I don't write all children at once.

Comment: You can create new child by `var newChild = new Person({ })` and then add it to your parent `parent.get('children').add(newChild)` where `parent` is existing Person at this moment.